# What's the quick and painless way to export CoreData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, core-data, export

I have an app with various entities built in Core Data, which is great, but I want to extract that data so I can build a database (for research purposes).

What's the quick and painless way to export CoreData entities from an iPhone?

I've been searching around and there seems to be a lot of suggestions, everything looks pretty messy. I started manually writing code to export it as CSV but that's a lot of work and if I change my database I need to change the CSV exporter to match.

There must be a really easy way to do it, no?

Can you take the SQLite file and import it into something else?
Doesn't Apple provide any APIs to export CoreData?

EDIT: Don't need anything fancy like exporting to a web service. I just want to export the data so I can manage it on a desktop, perhaps in Access, Excel, anything like that. It's not going to be a crazy amount of data, and this is mostly a temporary solution.

EDIT2: Found this program: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/
It's pretty much everything you need. Includes CSV export.

Thanks for your help everyone

Comment: Export where? To a web service?

Comment: List the suggestions that you found too messy for you so that readers won't re-suggest them.

Comment: Maybe just copy over the SQLite3 database file?

Comment: Copy it over to where? (As in what programs will read that file?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Apple doesn't provide any APIs specifically for exporting your data.  You can use the existing APIs, but you have to do all the work yourself to export relationships and format the data.

If you want a quick and dirty solution, just copy the database file and use the `sqlite3` command on your Mac to extract the data.  Suppose the database file is named `store.db`.  You can look at its schema using this command:

```
sqlite3 store.db .schema
```

You should find it very easy to figure out which tables correspond to which entities and relationships.  For example, I have an entity named `LibraryEntry`.  It's represented by this table:

```
CREATE TABLE ZLIBRARYENTRY ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZGRIDHEIGHT INTEGER, ZGRIDWIDTH INTEGER, ZDYNAMICDATARELATION INTEGER, ZORIGINALDATARELATION INTEGER, ZTHUMBNAILDATARELATION INTEGER, ZDATE TIMESTAMP, ZAUTHOR VARCHAR, ZSIGNATURE VARCHAR, ZTITLE VARCHAR );
```

The columns that start with `Z_` are Core Data's internal metadata.  Of those, you probably only care about `Z_PK`.  The other columns (which start with `Z` but no underscore) are the attributes of `LibraryEntry`.

To dump a table in CSV, use a command like this:

```
sqlite3 -csv store.db 'select * from zentity' > entity.csv
```

If you want a header line, use the `-header` flag, like this:

```
sqlite3 -header -csv store.db 'select * from zentity' > entity.csv
```